# org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/core/JavascriptModelException

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jakarta-ee

sometimes i get the following error in eclipse:

**org/eclipse/wst/jsdt/core/JavascriptModelException**

any ideas why to get this error and how to fix it ?